# remove a character from a json file using bash

Tags: bash

this is the first time I use **bash**, I would like to remove from this line

*...false], [false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false]], ] }*

the last , placed before the last square bracket, any advice?

Comment: You should fix the process that generates malformed JSON upstream

Answer (score 0):

You can do the removing with `sed`:

```bash
$ echo "...false], [false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false]], ] }" | sed 's/, *]/ ]/g'
...false], [false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false]] ] }
```

Note that it also would be applied to a `, ]` sequence placed inside a string, which is not desired I guess. Full parsing is needed for covering all possible cases.